# Background-position ignored by Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, background-position

I'm having a problem with positioning two background images in Chrome.
In FF and IE the images are right where I want them to be, but in Chrome they both just sit in the top left corner.
So Chrome ignores the background-position property.
When I remove the 150px from that property, it works, but I want the images 150px from the bottom.

```
#wrap {width:100%; position:relative;z-index:1; background-color:#ebebeb; background-image: url("/portals/0/images/bosch_rechtsonder.png"),url("/portals/0/images/meba_linksmidden.png"); background-position: right bottom 150px, left bottom 150px; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-attachment: scroll, scroll;}
```

Does anyone have another solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by giving 3 values?

```
background-position: right bottom 150px, left bottom 150px;
```

The value `right` is fine, `bottom` is fine. Why is the `150px` there? Remove it. Change it to:

```
background-position: right bottom, left bottom;
```

You know that it is a fixed positioning of `150px` from the bottom. The only way is to give 150px of whitespace or setting it transparent using an **image editor** and put it on the background. It cannot be controlled by pure CSS, without knowing the element's `height`.

Comment: Did you see `When I remove the 150px from that property, it works, but I want the images 150px from the bottom`?

Comment: `bottom 150px` or `right 150px` is also valid, but not `right bottom 150px`

Comment: @Xymostech I didn't. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I solved it by adding transparent pixels to my images.